# Detect Symfony version by folders. How?

Tags: symfony1

I have a symfony project. It's not mine. I wanna to understand the version in which the project is written. It do not seem to be a 2.0 version. 
The project folder structure is this:

```
-test
-plugins
-nbprojects
-log
-lib
-data
-config
-cache
-apps
-.git

files
-test.txt
-symfony
-kill.sh
-index.html
-ftp.sh
-ftp_1.sh
-ftp_2.sh
data.txt
another
.readme_notes.swo
```

Any idea of which version of Symfony this is and how to do in order to start modify this project?

Comment: try navigtating into cd your_project_folder
symfony --version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why You want to recognize symfony versions, but you can for e.g check:

- for symfony 1.x - index.php file in web folder
- symfony 2.x.x - app.php file in web folder

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a symfony1 project.

To have a precise idea of the version, as @cpntk said, once in the project directory, just run:

```
php symfony --version
```